# RabbitMQ error: .Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I am starting RabbitMQ Tutorial,
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

For some reason, I am receiving error below. Anyone receive this error when starting Rabbit mq, and any solutions? Just started programming few months ago. How would I resolve this?

> Unhandled Exception: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (IP address)

This is on my local desktop pc.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall?

Comment: This is on my local desktop Dell pc., don't think I have a firewall

Comment: Also make sure your RabbitMQ server start successfully and make it listen on the required port

Comment: how would I do that, and find required port?

Comment: Have you installed the server ? https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html

Comment: Buddy, Did you find the fix?